# Grafana Base64 Image/Video/Audio/PDF plugins unable to display

Tags: image, grafana, monitoring

Does anyone know why is the field name and field description is empty ?
According to the document https://volkovlabs.io/plugins/volkovlabs-image-panel/formats/ there will be output at the field name and field description accordingly

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7xjI.png)

I had try according to the document https://volkovlabs.io/plugins/volkovlabs-image-panel/formats/ there will be output at the field name and field description accordingly, but there is none in my local